# bracket is wrapping body

Tags: string, next.js, brackets

[image]

Hi, guys..

I've never seen this problem, so i need help.

This is my index.js code, i didn't write bracket in string. but there is suddenly..

If you know this problem, please let me know.

```
import Center from "../components/Center";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-black h-screen overflow-hidden">
      <main className="">
        <Sidebar />
        <Center />
      </main>
      <div>{/* player */}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add your `_app.js` as well that wraps your `Home` page.
Maybe something is going on there.
Also just to debug, comment/clear everything on root (i.e _app.js) and begin adding pages/components.

Comment: Oh... !! Thanks guys, i found problem, that was in my _app.js ㅠ_ㅠ